# Как обратиться к div внутри div

Tags: html, css, html5

Здравствуйте.

Есть блок и внутри него ещё два блока. Хочу чтобы первый внутренний блок занимал левую часть экрана (50% экрана), а второй блок правую (50% экрана). Пробовал сделать сам, но так и не получилось. Не могу достучаться до `div'ов` внутри `#father`.

Пример:

```css
#son {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px margin-left: auto;
}
#daughter {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="son">....</div>
  <div id="daughter">....</div>
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вам стоит больше узнать о селекторах, что бы понять как обращаться к тем или иным элементам [почитайте это](https://html5book.ru/osnovy-css/)

Comment: При чем тут `селекторы` ?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk да, виновата моя невнимательность. Не правильно понял смысл последнего предложения автора

Comment: У тебя ещё в стилях для  обоих селекторов ошибка `width: 300px margin-right: auto;`, тут не стоит точки с запятой после значения `300px` для ширины, а значит, свойство не применилось вообще. Судя по всему у тебя просто не хватает знаний по CSS, почитай побольше про свойства стилей и как их задавать правильно, сами основы. Потому что вопрос мягко говоря для очень начинающих.

Comment: @VostokSisters Здравствуй увжаемый .Да так оно и есть я только как 3-4 дня с CSS знаком .Спасибо за совет .Обезательно займусь этим

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#son{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#daughter{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="son"></div><div id="daughter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а можете сказать что сделали и где моя ошибка?

Comment: @elik для начала вы забыли кавычки после длины. margin здесь лишний (отступы же вам не нужны?). В данном случае ключевое свойство – display. Почитайте про него. Также этого эффекта можно добиться через float, как в ответе C.Raf.T

Comment: @Vednin спасибо дорогой приятель

Comment: Хорошо и плохо автор ответа поступает специально убирая перенос строки между дочерними элементами и никак не комментирует это? Минус

Answer (score 2):

```css
#father {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#son {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}
#daughter {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="father">

  <div id="son"></div>
  <div id="daughter"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, с использованием `flex`, т.к. `float` уже морально устарели :)

p.s. Добавил `border` для демонстрации

```css
#father {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#son, #daughter{
  height: 400px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#daughter{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="son">....</div>
  <div id="daughter">....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Солидарен насчет флоат)

Comment: ))))))))Спасибо буду иметь ввиду